# Is there a bounded non-blocking Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

The only one I can find is the BoundedFIFOBuffer, which is deprecated.  Any others?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`BoundedFIFOBuffer` in Apache Commons Collections (which I assume is what you're referring to) is not deprecated, it has just moved packages. The original one in `org.apache.commons.collections` is deprecated, and has instead been moved to `org.apache.commons.collections.buffer`

Comment: Thanks, somehow I landed on the deprecated page.

Answer (score 14):

Why not just use a [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) and use the non-blocking methods `offer` (or `add`) and `poll` to access it?  You can create it with a fixed capacity (i.e. to make it bounded).

Comment: Probably not worth being concerned about, but LinkedBlockingQueue will still take a lock.  Future versions of hotspot can probably optimize that away.  But something to be aware of when profiling later on.

Answer (score 3):

There are some bounded collections in Apache [commons-collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), including a [BoundedFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/BoundedFifoBuffer.html).

In the same library, is also [BoundedBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/BoundedBuffer.html) and [CircularFifoBuffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) recently.  I think you could have a Java Generics solution pretty easily with it.  There is a class called [ForwardingList](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) which I think you could implement this idea pretty easily.  Obviously not as easy as just using BoundedFifoBuffer (non-generic) or ArrayBlockingQueue.

```
final ArrayList<MyObject> realList = Lists.newArrayList();
final List<MyObject> list = new ForwardingList<MyObject>() {
    protected List<MyObject> delegate() {
        return realList;
    }

    public boolean add(MyObject obj) {
        if(delegate().size() > 100) return false;
        return delegate().add(obj);
    }
};
```