# Does java provide capped collection

Tags: java

For example, a capped list which automatically delete the first inserted items if the total items pass the specified amount? Any builtin or 3rd party support?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a bounded non-blocking Collection in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290112/is-there-a-bounded-non-blocking-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered here in this Stackoverflow question:

[Is there a bounded non-blocking Collection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290112/is-there-a-bounded-non-blocking-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It would be fairly trivial to implement this as a wrapper for any of the queue type java collections.