# Fixed number of generic objects which can be iterated over

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have a class which always holds four objects:

```
class Foo<E> {
    Cow<E> a, b, c, d;
}
```

I want to be able to iterate over them, so ideally I'd like to use an array:

```
class Foo<E> {
    Cow<E>[] cows = new Cow<E>[4]; // won't work, can't create generic array
}
```

I don't want to use a list or a set since I want there to always be 4 Cow objects. What's the best solution for me?

Comment: You can't have generic arrays. Why don't you want to use a List?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation

Comment: I don't want to use a list for two reasons. The first is that you can add and remove elements to and from a list. The second is that I'm creating a quadtree data structure and using a list wouldn't be too good for performance. Quadtrees have a lot of quadrants and using lists would decrease performance significantly.

Comment: that's a lot of assumptions you have there...

Comment: implements iterable and a iterator inside your class. see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4533698/1122645

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the genericity, you will have to reimplement something similar to a list and I don't think it is worth it.

You said:

> The first is that you can add and remove elements to and from a list.

Well you can create an unmodifiable list:

```
List<E> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d));
```

> The second is that I'm creating a quadtree data structure and using a list wouldn't be too good for performance. Quadtrees have a lot of quadrants and using lists would decrease performance significantly.

First you can initialise the list to the right size:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<>(4);
```

Once you have done that, the list will only use a little bit more memory than an array (probably 8 bytes: 4 byte for the backing array reference and another 4 byte for the size).

And in terms of performance [an ArrayList performs almost as good as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565376/829571).

**Bottom line**: I would start by using a list and measure the performance. If it is not good enough AND it is due to using  a list instead of an array, then you will have to adapt your design - but I doubt that this will be your main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a generic `ArrayList` and simply have methods to insert values into your object, and do checks inside those methods, to make sure you don't end up having more than 4 `Cow` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collection` instead of `array`:

```
List<Cow<E>> cows = new ArrayList<>(); // in Java 7
```

Or

```
List<Cow<E>> cows = new ArrayList<Cow<E>>(); //Java 6 and below
```

More information will show why it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to have arrays whit `generics`. You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java/2927427#2927427)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest creating a bounded list. Java does not have an inbuilt one however you can create a custom one using Google collections or use the one in Apache collections. See [Is there a bounded non-blocking Collection in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290112/is-there-a-bounded-non-blocking-collection-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
Cow<E>[] cows = (Cow<E>[])new Cow[4];
```

or

```
Cow<E>[] cows = (Cow<E>[])new Cow<?>[4];
```